# Multiple line with underline in UIButton title in iOS-5

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, ios7, uibutton

I want to create underlined button link following image in iOS.
[image]

I already used [UIUnderlineButton](https://gist.github.com/zypsg/2214495)

so it gives me following output.

[image]

please help me to achieve underlined button like 1st image.

Comment: You can use a UIButton with an attributed title. I'm not sure.

Comment: Try `setAttributedTitle:forState` with the an attributedString with `NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName`

Comment: can i use setAttributedTitle:forState in ios5 ?

Comment: No, this method was introduced in iOS6.

Comment: use https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel

Comment: i want to do this in iOS-5 also

Comment: @MaulikKundaliya bhai...check out my answer.

Comment: @Goti : this works only in iOS-6 or above but i also do this in iOS-5.

Comment: @Goti : in which way you achieve this in iOS-5 ?

Comment: @MaulikKundaliya I have only done it for ios6 and above

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick for iOS6 and above, using attributedString:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"yourTextButton"];
[attrStr addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:@(NSUnderlineStyleSingle) range:NSMakeRange(0, [attrStr length])];
[yourButton setAttributedTitle:attrStr forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[yourButton titleLabel] setNumberOfLines:0];//Multiple Lines
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a UILabel and  [UITapGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITapGestureRecognizer) when your text is this long and you don't need any additional classes.

Comment: You can't set a highlight color when the user taps the UILabel then.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. I hope it is what you want.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *titleString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Tap here...."];
    [titleString addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:NSUnderlineStyleSingle] range:NSMakeRange(0, [titleString length])];
    [titleString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blackColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, [titleString length])];
    [_button setAttributedTitle: titleString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```